# Little rear rotor clearance

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, rotor

I have just test fit my wheel on a Litespeed T5gravel that I'm building and I see there is less than 1mm of clearance between the rear rotor and the chain stay. The rotor is currently a 160mm avid Centerline, and I'd happily move to a 140 but from what I can tell you can't go down a size with this frame (the brake mount is part of the frame and seems to be built for 160).

Maybe it is fine but it is so close it seems like it will start rubbing even from thermal expansion. See the pic for what I'm talking about.

Any advice?

[image: clearance from rotor to chainstay]

Comment: There's nothing to move - no suspension.  So unless you warp the rotor it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm a little surprised that, since this is the only rotor size you can use on the frame at all, they didn't design with a little more clearance. Was going to build some new wheels for this bike and now I'll want to use the same hubs out of fear that another set might push out the rotor by a mm and be unusable!  But I'll ride it. Must be stiff like crazy in that part of the frame. This frame even has a cross brace on the brake side of the rear triangle near the back so I don't think it will flex. ...and less worry when taking the wheel on and off since it is unpainted Ti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that will be okay.  Have a look if there are no spacers behind the rotor mount bolts - or if it's center lock see if there is a spacer behind it as well.

Removing these may help.

Comment: 6 bolt ISO - no spacers, looks flush against the mounting surface. Thru axel so wheels should be well aligned (and they seem to be). It is 15mm from the edge of the dropout to the disc mounting surface, which I believe is to spec. Doesn't rub even with some torsion applied to the wheel, although it doesn't take much force with my finger against the rotor to make it rub.  Guessing it will be fine as well, but the same wheels on my other bike end up with like 12mm between the disc and stay so this was substantially different. Anyway - thanks for the comment!  Makes me feel better :)

Comment: Yeah just ride it - on my Litespeed Tanasi hard tail the gap is also very minimal.  Never had a problem.